# Nav tab not working with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<body>
  <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Products</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
      </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

This is the code in the body section.. Could yall please help me figure out whats going wrong? Im not able to see the contents in horizontal tabs :(

Comment: You are mixing [navbars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) and [tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs). This doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 6):

Before anything, you're mixing [v3](https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) markup while using a [v4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) CSS file. **They aren't interchangeable** so that's one issue.

You also need to apply `data-toggle="tab"` to each of your `a` tags regardless of the version you're using. Check out the documentation as far as `li` structure based on which version you are actually using.

### Working Examples of v3 & v4

**Bootstrap v3 Example:** See Tab [Markup](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#markup) & [Nav Tabs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Products</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#one" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">One</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#two" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Two</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#three" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Three</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#contact" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <div class="alert alert-info">Home</div>
    </div>
    <div id="one" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div class="alert alert-info">One</div>
    </div>
    <div id="two" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div class="alert alert-info">Two</div>
    </div>
    <div id="three" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div class="alert alert-info">Three</div>
    </div>
    <div id="contact" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div class="alert alert-info">Contact</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Bootstrap v4 Example:** See [Navs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#one">One</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#two">Two</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" href="#three">Three</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
      <div class="alert alert-info">Home</div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="one">
      <div class="alert alert-info">One</div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="two">
      <div class="alert alert-info">Two</div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="three">
      <div class="alert alert-info">Three</div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="contact">
      <div class="alert alert-info">Contact</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.4/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `navbar` then code will be like this.

```
 <nav class="navbar">  
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Products
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">three</a></li> 
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

More Information: [NavBar](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp)

If you want to use `Bootstrap tabs` then code will be like this.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Products <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">one</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">two</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">three</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Details: [Bootstrap tabs](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp)